# Schema Compare doesn't list all columns in a Change

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to update one table from one database to another database in visual studio 2012 using schema compare. The table exists in both databases, the first one has more columns than the one in the second db. The schema compare shows me that this table is different displaying me the new columns on the left size of the window.

When I try to generate the script for updating the table on the database in the right side, is creating a temp table but is not listing the whole columns, so it gives me an error in one column that is NOT NULL.

Any idea of this behavior? shouldn't be straightforward for this simple change?

Comment: The source table should be on the left and target table on the right - so likewise the new columns should show up on the right side not the left.

Comment: Are you trying to add column(s) or remove column(s)?

Comment: I'm trying to add columns

Comment: Are you trying to add a column that is specified as `NOT NULL`?

Comment: No, in fact the error its giving me in a column that already exists

Comment: Best to post the exact contents of the error message.